# Sorting a string array and an Int array side by side

Tags: c++, arrays

hope you can help. I've got another project to do and I'm a bit stuck. For this project we are making a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I have nearly everything set up for this, except the required highscore function. The Prof wants us to print out the top 3 highscores, in order of greatest score.

How I have my code set up is that I have 2 separate arrays, highscore[] and highscoreNames[]. I need to figure out how to sort highscore[] from greatest to smallest, but also keep the names from highscoreNames[] paired with their score.

Thanks for the help, and if you need anymore info ask!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use one container for the high score and the high score name:

```
struct High_Score_Info
{
  unsigned int score;
  std::string  name;
};

//...
std::vector<High_Score_Info> scores;
```

This will allow you to keep the score and the name together during sorting.

**Edit 1:**
If you are not allowed to use structures, you will need to write your own sort routine.  When you move items in the *score* array, also move the same items (same indices) of the *names* array.

Answer (score 0):

Structure is a better way to do this. Though just using the indexes could also help, sorting for scores and swapping in both the arrays :

```
for(i = 1; (i <= numLength); i++)
     {
          for (j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
         {
               if (highscore[j+1] > highscore[j])      
                { 
                    int temp = highscore[j];            
                    highscore[j] = highscore[j+1];
                    highscore[j+1] = temp;
                    string tempName = highscoreNames[j];            
                    highscoreNames[j] = highscoreNames[j+1];
                    highscoreNames[j+1] = temp;

               }
          }
     }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response, this seems like the one most likely to work with my code. Anyways, what is the variable numLength coming from? is it the size of my arrays? Sorry if its a stupid question, I'm still extremely new to C++

Comment: Ok, so for some reason, when using this it throws an error message popup with the text: Unhandled exception at 0x00F98A16 in Assign2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. Any idea why?

Comment: Just check the array bounds properly once and place them acc to your piece of code. Initialise the string tempName = "" before the loops. Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a formal pairing data structure, like the one @Thomas has suggested, or you can create a third array that contains the indeces of the sorted scores.  This way you don't need to actually reorder the data arrays.  For example, it might be something like this:

```
highscore = {5, 2, 4, 1, 6};
highscoreNames = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
sortedIndeces = {4, 0, 2, 1, 3};
```

Then, you just simply use `sortedIndeces` to index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    highscore[sortedIndeces[i]]; //6, 5, 4, 2, 1
    highscoreNames[sortedIndeces[i]]; //e, a, c, b, d
}
```